# Java: Send and receive KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE results to/from serial

Tags: java, serial-port, keyevent

My goal is a bit complicated and im not sure if its even possible. But im making a terminal program for a company i work for.

So the program is built this way (at least, the important part).
I have a `JTextArea` that is receiving the bytes read from the serial using the `JSSC` library. This `JTextArea` has a key listener that listens for a keypress and sends each keypress to the serial as an int using `SerialPort.writeInt(event.getKeyCode());` or `.getKeyChar();` i dont remember but i think its `getKeyChar();`. WHEN i press `Backspace`, on the JTextArea, lets say i typed in `reset halt` to reset the Control Module to factory defaults and to halt it. If i press `Backspace` 2 times, in the actual Control Module, it does "Backspace" 2 characters BUT on the JTextArea it will still display `reset halt` PLUS (the part i want to fix mainly) `[K` for each time i press `Backspace`. So...

1. I type in `reset halt`.
2. I press `Backspace` 2 times.
3. The result on my JTextArea is `reset halt[K[K`.
4. The result on the actual Control Module (which i cant see the results) is `reset ha` as it should be.

I thought that it was perhaps the keycode i was using, so i made an if statement to change what is being sent through the serial when i press `Backspace`.

```
if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE){
    SerialPort.writeInt(127); //Decimal for Delete
    //And (not at the same time)
    SerialPort.writeInt(8); //Decimal for Backspace (from ASCII code)
}
```

Of course i was wrong and the issue persists.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to "update" what is being "Backspaced" to my `JTextArea` by reading the serial?
2. How can i prevent the nasty `[K` from appearing on my console (`JTextArea`).

I don't need you to do the work for me, simply something to push me in the right direction.

**And i apologize for not putting much of my code on the question. Im at home and my workspace at work does not have internet (shocker) for "security reasons". If you need more code, please let me know and i will try to add it if i can!**

I also have a side question about something that i want to add/change in my console (`JTextArea`). I don't know the technical term for it but i want to increase width of the typing cursor on my console so its more visible, NOT THE MOUSE CURSOR, but the blinking cursor that shows up when you click on a textfield. What is that cursor called?

Comment: Do you need the capability to edit the content of the terminal ?

Comment: If you don't need the editing capability or any other capability that JTextArea supports then you can simply use JPanel's graphics object to directly write to it. Compared to overriding the default behavior of a component this should be much simpler given you may need to tweak something else in future.

Comment: @11thdimension interesting. could you provide an example or link? im not so sure i understand this JPanel graphics object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.

String is drawn using **graphics object** of MyTestPanel. Drawing is done inside **paintComponent()** of MyTestPanel.

KeyEvents are also detected by this panel as well. Since this doesn't have any default behavior you're free to do what you want with the given input.

I haven't handled the horizontal scrolling and panel dynamic width.

**TestFrame2**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestFrame2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShow();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final MyTestPanel panel = new MyTestPanel();

        //add any other components like buttons, labels to panel

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
        panel.setParentPane(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 300));
        frame.add(scrollPane);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosing(e);
                //panel.stopCursorThread();
            }
        });
        //frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.pack();
        //frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        System.out.println(frame.getWidth() + " : " + frame.getHeight());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //panel.startCursorThread();
    }
}
```

**MyTestPanel**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class MyTestPanel extends JPanel {
    final int LINE_HEIGHT = 20;
    final int START_X = 20;
    final int START_Y = 20;
    //private int lastLineY;

    final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    final StringBuilder lastLine = new StringBuilder();
    private JScrollPane parentPane;
    //Thread cursorThread;
    //private AtomicBoolean keepRunningCursor = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    String validCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,.\\/:;<=>?@[] ^_`{|}~-]*$";

    /*public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestFrame2.main(null);
    }*/

    public MyTestPanel() {
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 300));
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char ch = e.getKeyChar();
                if (isPrintableChar(ch)) {
                    lastLine.append(ch);
                    repaint();
                } else if (ch == '\b') {
                    if (lastLine.length() > 0) {
                        lastLine.deleteCharAt(lastLine.length() - 1);
                        repaint();
                    }
                } else if (ch == '\n') {
                    lines.add(lastLine.toString());
                    lastLine.delete(0, lastLine.length());
                    repaintAndUpdate();
                }
                updateScrollbar();
                System.out.println("textContent " + lastLine);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
                    System.out.println("BackSpace pressed");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateScrollbar() {
        if (parentPane != null) {
            JScrollBar vertical = parentPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            System.out.println(vertical.getMaximum() + " : " + parentPane.getHeight() + " : " + (vertical.getMaximum() - parentPane.getHeight()) + " : " + vertical.getHeight());
            vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum() - parentPane.getHeight() + parentPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getHeight());
        }
    }
    private void repaintAndUpdate() {
        int linesHeight = START_Y + lines.size() * LINE_HEIGHT + LINE_HEIGHT;//+LINE_HEIGHT just trial and error
        if(linesHeight > parentPane.getHeight()) {
            System.out.println(getHeight() + " : " + (getHeight() + LINE_HEIGHT));
            super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight() + LINE_HEIGHT) );
            parentPane.updateUI();
            super.revalidate();
            System.out.println(getHeight());

            repaint();
        }
    }

    private boolean isPrintableChar(char ch) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (validCharacters.indexOf(ch) != -1) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /*public void startCursorThread() {
        final Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        final int blinkInterval = 500;//miliseconds
        final int cursorWidth = 5;
        final int cursorHeight = LINE_HEIGHT;

        cursorThread = new Thread () {
            public void run () {
                boolean showCursor = true;
                while(keepRunningCursor.get()) {
                    localSleep(blinkInterval);
                    int x = START_X + g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(lastLine.toString());
                    //int y = START_Y + lines.size() * LINE_HEIGHT - LINE_HEIGHT + LINE_HEIGHT/3;
                    int y = lastLineY - (int)(2/3.0 * LINE_HEIGHT);
                    if(showCursor) {
                        g.fillRect(x, y, cursorWidth, cursorHeight);
                        g.drawRect(x - 50, y - 50, 100, 100);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g.fillRect(x, y, cursorWidth, cursorHeight);
                        g.drawRect(x - 50, y - 50, 100, 100);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    showCursor = !showCursor;

                    System.out.printf("%d %d %d %d\n", x, y, cursorWidth, cursorHeight);
                    //MyTestPanel.this.repaint(x, y, cursorWidth, cursorHeight);
                }

            }

            public void localSleep(long sleepTime) {
                try {
                    sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };

        cursorThread.start(); 
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int y = START_Y;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++, y += LINE_HEIGHT) {
            g.drawString(lines.get(i), START_X, y);
        }
        if (lastLine.length() > 0) {
            g.drawString(lastLine.toString(), START_X, y);
        }
        int x = START_X + g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(lastLine.toString());
        //cursor
        g.fillRect(x + 2, y - (int)(2/3.0 * LINE_HEIGHT), 5, 20);
        //lastLineY = y;
    }

    public void setParentPane(JScrollPane parentPane) {
        this.parentPane = parentPane;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(parentPane.getWidth(), parentPane.getHeight()));
    }

    /*public void stopCursorThread() {
        this.keepRunningCursor.set(false);
        System.out.println("Stopped cursor thread");
    }*/
}
```

**Output screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time in making this. ill have to try this out tomorrow. Thanks!